# Не работает $mail->send() в PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, smtp

Пытаюсь написать учебный проект на php. Нужно создать форму для отправки письма на email, обработать адрес получателя в js скрипте и сделать запрос к php скрипту на отправку письма.

Вот моя форма и js скрипт:

```js
function processForm() {
    let emailRecipient = document.getElementsByName('EmailRecipient')[0].value;
    let emailMessage = document.getElementsByName('Message')[0].value;

    if (checkEmail(emailRecipient) && emailMessage) {
        let form = document.getElementById('emailForm');
        let formData = new FormData(form);

        postRequest('emailSender.php', formData);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        showMessage('You have entered an invalid email address!');
        return false;
    }
}

function postRequest(url, data) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => showMessage(response.text()))
        .catch(error => showMessage(error));
}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }

    return response;
}

function showMessage(responseText) {
    console.log(responseText);
}

function checkEmail(email) {
    let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="emailForm">
            <div>
                <p>To:</p>
                <input type="text" name="EmailRecipient">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Message:</p>
                <textarea name="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="SendEmail" onclick="return processForm();">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="formHandler.js"></script>

</html>
```

А вот код на php:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$emailRecipient = '';
$message = '';

if (isset($_POST["EmailRecipient"]) && isset($_POST["Message"])) {
    $emailRecipient = $_POST["EmailRecipient"];
    $message = $_POST["Message"];
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->setFrom("username@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = $message;

$mail->AddAddress($emailRecipient);

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Error!";
} else {
    echo "Successful!";
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда выполнение php скрипта доходит до $mail->send(), я получаю ошибку 502 bad gateway. После этого php скрипт вообще перестает реагировать на любые запросы. Даже при измении кода и в том случае, если я оставляю просто echo "hello!" - вообще ничего не происходит, просто висит бесконечный pending как на картинке ниже. И так до тех пор, пока не перезапустится сервер.

В чем может быть проблема такого поведения? Что я делаю не так? Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы запускаете встроенный сервер php, то при каждом изменении скриптов сервер нужно перезагружать. Если же вы хотите увидеть ошибки на странице, то воспользуйтесь в коде конструкцией `try ... catch ...`

Comment: @ArchDemon Я пробовал использовать try-catch и перезагружать сервер. Я запускаю свой код из одной папки на локальном хосте из phpstorm. Обнаружил, что любые запросы из php скрипта почему-то возвращают 502 bad gateway. К примеру: `$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");`. То есть, всё что не касается запросов внутри скрипта -- работает. echo выводит значения `$_POST["EmailRecipient"];` и т.д. Но если я делаю любой запрос -- получаю 502 bad gateway. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Читайте логи сервера

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не очень разобрался с настройкой сервера и phpstorm. Я думал, что он автоматически подтягивает сервер и его конфигурацию при установке. Всё-таки выполнял же он на localhost простые скрипты без запросов нормально. 
Но оказалось, что phpstorm нуждается в ручной конфигурации. Для себя пока нашел выход: работать с проектом с корневой папки сервера. В моем случае это XAMPP и путь C:\xampp\htdocs. Если запускать проект оттуда, то запросы идут корректно. Вроде еще можно настроить mapping из произвольной директории.